# make does not build vxl

Tags: makefile, cmake, itk

I have been trying to build [vxl](http://vxl.sourceforge.net/) using cmake and then running make to use with ITK, but every time I do make the build, it fails, and I get the following error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d60sc.png)

Comment: On Stack Overflow we expect the error message to be in the question post **as text**, not linked as image. Please, grap textual representation of the error message, and paste it into the question post; then format it as a code.

Comment: When the error message is copy-pasted as text, it allows other people with similar problem to find the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build VXL before building ITK. VNL, the part of VXL which ITK used is already included in [ITK source code](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/tree/master/Modules/ThirdParty/VNL/src/vxl). Just build ITK, and as part of that process VNL will be built too.